# Would using Hazelcast for storing global constants be considered an abuse?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, hazelcast

I've been using Hazelcast recently and because I quite like it, I'm at the risk of succumbing to The [Law of the Instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) , or "to a hammer all problems are nails"

I'm wondering about how ridiculous it would be to store static final data, such as the list of countries for a web app because it is a kind convenient/lazy way to make it happen.

Given that HazelCast's design goal is really for distributed mutative state how appalling an idea would this really be and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your static data doesn't fit in a single JVM memory then you can consider storing in Hazelcast but for small amount of data it will be over-engineering. Keep things local if you can to avoid the cost of possible serialization, networking, clustering etc.

founder@hazelcast

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's appalling, particularly if you already have this technology in your project. Very little data is actually static anyway. Countries in particular change over time. Try finding Yugoslavia on a modern map of Europe... And where in the heck did the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics disappear to :).

Comment: Interesting point that server uptime could be better than several physical states